# api call fails with request module in node.js app

Tags: node.js

The following API call fails for me when I try it in my app. It works fine from same machine in the browser. I should get a JSON response.

```
var url = 'http://www.btc38.com/trade/getTradeList.php?coinname=BTC';

request.get({ url: url, json: json, strictSSL: false, headers: { 'User-Agent' : '' } }, function (err, resp, data) {
});
```

edit: by "fails" i mean i get a non-json error page.

Comment: Fails how?  Does it give a non 200 range response? Does it raise an exception? Does it timeout? Does it spawn a rift in the space time continuum?

Comment: non-json error page in html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use an empty `User-Agent` header, otherwise the request fails.

So use something like:

```
'User-Agent' : 'request/x.y'
```